# Photoshop Javascript apply Filter Gallery

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Using javascript, how can i apply **filterGallery>>posterEdges**(edgeThickness=7, edgeIntensity=1, posterization=6) and other 3rd party filter on **active layer** ??

Comment: What do the docs say?

Comment: Do you think i am nuts ?? i found nothing relative in documentation that's why i asked here. If you know the answer then share here.

Comment: You’re not nuts. Don’t be so hard on yourself!